# Modify Select with Variable such that it can be used in a Set operation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following code where I am selecting the LossAmount value from a table where I create a sequence column along with my LossAmount column, and picking the LossAmount value depending on a specific sequence number.

```
declare @percent float
set @percent = 0.95

select LossAmount
from (select LossAmount, seq = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by LossAmount desc) from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss) as p
where p.seq =((select COUNT(*) from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss)-((select COUNT(*) from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss)*@percent))
```

So say my LossAmount column has 1000 rows, the p.seq equation is `1000-1000(0.95)`.  I am picking the LossAmount value at that sequence number (which is 50).

In my case, my parameter is a scalar.
How can I update my code if I have a variety of percents I want to calculate? I have the following table, dbo.Percentiles

```
Percentiles
0.4
0.6
0.996
```

For my output, I would like something like this.

```
Percentiles   LossAmount
0.4           ...some #...
0.6           ...some #...
0.996         ...some #...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A UDF should work (cross apply or select clause), but it is also likely horribly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do you, there are cleaner ways to write it, but I wanted to change your code as little as possible...

```
select  LossAmount, n.percentiles
from   (select  LossAmount, 
                seq = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by LossAmount desc) 
        from    dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss) as p
join   (Select ((select COUNT(*) from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss)-((select COUNT(*) from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss)*percentiles)) As seq, percentiles
        From    dbo.Percentiles) n
        On  p.seq = n.seq
```

Comment: In this case, I'm only receiving the LossAmount value at that sequence which is perfect.  I'm trying to do another case where I want the SUM of the LossAmount up to that sequence divided by the sequence. Say my sequence is 10 for one percentile.  I want `SUM(LossAmount)/10` where the LossAmount values are only up to sequence 10.  What's the best way to do this for each percentile? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my mind around what you're saying... If you were to add tables populated with data and the desired output it is much much easier. I'll think on this a bit and see if I can get you something.

Comment: Say the sequence is 10 for one percentile.  Basically instead of the output just being the LossAmount at sequence 10, add up all the LossAmount values where sequence is 1-10 and divide that by 10.   Do this for all three percentiles since the sequence is different for all 3. (What I'm doing is just finding the average of the LossAmount values at or below that sequence).  Thank you again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is always harder than I think it should be.  The challenge is getting one row out.  I think the following does it:

```
select pt.pcent, min(LossAmount)
from (select tl.*, p.pcent, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by LossAmount desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as totnum
      from dbo.TestXB_TotalLoss cross join
           (select 0.95 as pcent
           ) p
     ) pt
where totnum*pcent - seqnum >= 0 and totnum*pcent - seqnum < 1
```

This moves the percents into an inner table `p` and does a cross join.  It then selects the rows where the difference between the planned row number (`totnum*pcent`) and the actual row number (`seqnum`) is non-negative and less than 1.

I haven't tested this particular query, so it might have syntax errors.